# MongoDB and data granulation

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

My DB is filled with records:

```
{date: ISODate("2015-04-04T10:01Z"), sentence: "Lorem ipsum"}
{date: ISODate("2015-04-04T20:31Z"), sentence: "dolor sit"}
{date: ISODate("2016-05-04T03:55Z")} // No `sentence` here
{date: ISODate("2017-01-04T09:10Z"), sentence: "amet,"}
{date: ISODate("2019-02-04T19:30Z"), sentence: "consectetur adipiscing"}
```

Say, user would like to print the first sentence that occurs in a given month, between 2015 and 2018. Obviously, the response would be:

```
{date: ISODate("2015-04-04T10:01Z"), sentence: "Lorem ipsum"}
{date: ISODate("2017-01-04T09:10Z"), sentence: "amet,"}
```

However, it would not be efficient if my DB would have millions of records and the range is between wide year span. I probably need some clever algorithm to granulate those data. First guess is to skip every N months from results (maybe using aggregation framework?). Is it possible to do such an operation within a single query, with the use of MongoDB driver?

At first glance, it looks like a trivial example of granulation, but I couldn't find any example around the internet.

*Also, I am talking about months, but what if I would like to extend the request, and add grouping by days, hours, etc. in the future?*

**Edit:**

I am sorry, I think I wasn't precise enough. I actually know it's possible to group by year, month, day, etc., but more I am interested in, is the way of how can we build the *clever algorithm to granulate those data*:

```
Max = 30 /// I don't want to present more than 30 sentences at once

If userDidAskForMoreThanMaxResults {
    return Granulate() // The real problem for me starts here
} else {
    return FelixAnswer()
}
```

Please note, that granulation is not `$limit`, it's more like using `$sample` operator, but with uniform distribution instead.

Comment: I think what you want is `$group` by [`$month`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/month/) and [`$year`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/year/) and retrieve the [`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/year/) sentence. [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort) your document by date in ascending order if you decide to go with `$first` and descending if `$last`.

Comment: You may want to filter out the documents without the "sentence" key using the [`$exists`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) operator and `$match` prior to the sorting.

Comment: @styvane, not quite - please check my edited question.

Answer (score 1):

As styvane explained in his comment, ou can achieve this with the aggregation framework. 
You can extract the **year**, **month**, **day**, **hours** ect from an `ISODate()` using operators like **`$year`**

To get only the first record of each month, you can group record by Year/Month and keep the first **sentence** like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
    "$match": {
        "sentence": {
            "$exists": true
        }
    }
}, {
    "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "year": {
                "$year": "$date"
            },
            "month": {
                "$month": "$date"
            }
        },
        "date": {
            "$first": "$date"
        },
        "sentence": {
            "$first": "$sentence"
        }
    }
}])
```

you can try it here: [mongoplayground.net/p/NiH_GY8i3lJ](https://mongoplayground.net/p/NiH_GY8i3lJ)

Comment: Thanks @felix however, I think I didn't explain well what's the main point of my question. I am more looking for a granulation algorithm (_MongoDB and data granulation_), than how can I group results into months, days, etc. Please check my edited question.

Comment: @joe.kovalski Then you should go with **`$sample`**. What makes you thing that it doesn't have uniform distribution ? If it's not good enough, I'm afraid you'll have to to it manually with an algo of your own...

Comment: are you the author of mongoplayground.net? I am getting **error(s) found in config or query** when executing script from your link

Comment: Solution worked nice and perfect +1 @joe.kovalski I guess some issue with tool. You need to toggle Mode to mgodatagen and back to json. It's working fine for me then :)